# ActionBarSherlock library cannot find onActionModeStarted() - And 256 similar errors

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I've been trying to create a new project using the files provided at [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com). Here is what I did, step by step:

1. Create new Android Project
2. Create Project from Existing Source
3. Locate the /library folder in the ActionBarSherlock directory
4. Choose 4.03 as SDK target.
5. Finish!
6. Add android-support-v4 as Library

Now this imported the project as expected but with roughly 256 errors. Below you'll see a screendump of some of them. What is going on ?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/m6e70.png]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to your `project properties` (right click on your project) > `Java Compiler` and switch the compliance level from 1.5 to 1.6. I struggled quite a few hours with this as well..

[image: ActionBar Sherlock compliance level]

Comment: Thank you - This solved most of my problems. Only one error remains now.

"Cannot reduce the visibility of the inherited method from FragmentActivity" in the method protected void supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(). Would there be problems with making this method public?

Comment: I'd rather make the subclasses method protected. Thanks for checking this answer, good luck with your projects!

Answer (score -1):

Check your project dependencies.